# How do I get MUI and react-grid-dnd to work together?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

MUI requires a much newer version of react (17.0.0+), while react-grid-dnd only works on react 16.8.6 at the latest. Is there a way to update react-grid-dnd, or an alterative for dragable boxes like in the following sample?

https://codesandbox.io/s/de2s1

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

**react-grid-dnd** has a peer dependency to **React 16.8.6** – yes. However, it does work with **React 17.0.0+**. I haven't experienced any flaws so far experimenting with this combination.

In order for you to get the installation running you have to run the following commands in your terminal:

```
npm i react-grid-dnd --legacy-peer-deps
npm i react-gesture-responder --legacy-peer-deps
```

The **--legacy-peer-deps** tells npm to ignore peer dependencies and proceed with the installation anyway.